# std::uniform_real_distribution gives only one number at mingw

Tags: c++, mingw, distribution, mt19937

I am try to run this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>

void foo() {
  std::random_device rd;
  std::mt19937 mt(rd());
  std::uniform_real_distribution<double> prob(0, 1);
  std::cout << prob(mt) << '\n';
}

int main() {
  for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
    foo();
  }
  return 0;
}
```

At the mingw-w64\x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0\mingw64 I get this result:

```
0.726249
0.726249
0.726249
0.726249
0.726249
```

But on the ideone and g++ I get different numbers. So what the problem?

Comment: `random_device` used to be broken in MinGW, it was fixed in GCC 9.2. Either update your compiler or seed using `std::time(nullptr)` or something else. One way to get the latest and greatest MinGW GCC is from MSYS2.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat  Even if `std::random_device` is broken and produces the same number each time, it just initializes the state of `mt` and is no longer referenced after construction. Shouldn't the output be 5 differing values but produce the same sequence each time the program is run if only `std::random_device` is broken?